# Omitir atributo do DTO (Spring Data JPA)

Tags: jpa, restful, spring-jpa

Olá, tenho duas classes DTO (CategoriaDTO e ProdutoDTO) em uma aplicação restfull, como posso omitir um determinado atributo do ProdutoDTO quando ele for utilizado na classe CategoriaDTO? Abaixo seguem as classes, o retorno no Postman, e o que estou querendo realizar. Grato.

CategoriaDTO

```
package com.eclodir.voucomprei.dto;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

import com.eclodir.voucomprei.domain.Categoria;

public class CategoriaDTO implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private Long id;
    private String descricao;
    private String foto;
    private List<ProdutoDTO> produtos = new ArrayList<>();

    public CategoriaDTO() {}
    public CategoriaDTO(Categoria obj) {
        this.id = obj.getId();
        this.descricao = obj.getDescricao();
        this.foto = obj.getFoto();
        this.produtos = obj.getProdutos().stream().map(x -> new ProdutoDTO(x)).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getDescricao() {
        return descricao;
    }
    public void setDescricao(String descricao) {
        this.descricao = descricao;
    }
    public String getFoto() {
        return foto;
    }
    public void setFoto(String foto) {
        this.foto = foto;
    }
    public List<ProdutoDTO> getProdutos() {
        return produtos;
    }
    public void setProdutos(List<ProdutoDTO> produtos) {
        this.produtos = produtos;
    }

}
```

ProdutoDTO

```
package com.eclodir.voucomprei.dto;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import com.eclodir.voucomprei.domain.Categoria;
import com.eclodir.voucomprei.domain.Produto;

public class ProdutoDTO implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private Long id;
    private String descricao;
    private String foto;
    private String fabricante;
    private String unidade;
    private List<String> categorias = new ArrayList<>(); // Esta lista recebe as descrições das categorias

    public ProdutoDTO() {
    }

    public ProdutoDTO(Produto obj) {
        super();
        this.id = obj.getId();
        this.descricao = obj.getDescricao();
        this.foto = obj.getFoto();
        this.fabricante = obj.getFabricante();
        this.unidade = obj.getUnd().getDescricao();

        // Recebendo as descriçoes das categorias
        for (Categoria x : obj.getCategorias()) {
            if (x != null) {
                categorias.add(x.getDescricao());
            }
        }

    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getDescricao() {
        return descricao;
    }

    public void setDescricao(String descricao) {
        this.descricao = descricao;
    }

    public String getFoto() {
        return foto;
    }

    public void setFoto(String foto) {
        this.foto = foto;
    }

    public String getFabricante() {
        return fabricante;
    }

    public void setFabricante(String fabricante) {
        this.fabricante = fabricante;
    }

    public String getUnidade() {
        return unidade;
    }

    public void setUnidade(String unidade) {
        this.unidade = unidade;
    }

    public List<String> getCategorias() {
        return categorias;
    }

    public void setCategorias(List<String> categorias) {
        this.categorias = categorias;
    }

}
```

Retorno no endpoint de listagem da categoria:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como podem ver, no retorno do entpoint cada categoria mostra sua lista de produtos, porém, cada produto traz as categorias que este faz parte, Isto devido o ProdutoDTO conter este atributo que é importante em outros processos. Existe alguma forma de omitir as categorias dentro do detalhamento do produto? Procuro uma alternativa que não seja criar outro DTO sem este atributo para ser utilizado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Existe uma *annotation* chamada `@JsonIgnore` queser reconhecida pelo Jackson, que é a biblioteca default usada pelo Spring para conversões de Json. O Jackson irá identificar que você não deseja serializar essa campo. No seu caso, sua entidade ficaria algo assim:

```
public class Produto {

   @JsonIgnore
   private List<Categoria> categorias;   

//...
```

Se entendi de forma incorreta sua dúvida ou se precisar de algo mais, deixe um comentário que eu altero a resposta para te ajudar mais.

Comment: Oi, tudo bem? Existe alguma forma do JsonIgnore ser seletivo? Por exemplo, dentro de um endpoint que retorna uma lista o atributo é ignorado, já em um endpoint que retorna o próprio objeto o atributo é exibido.